# Stream Audio files without delay and without being downloadable : Jwplayer and AWS S3

Tags: html, amazon-s3, jwplayer, audio-streaming, jwplayer7

How can I stream audio file from S3 bucket to web/mobile using jwplayer without making them those

```
 jwplayer('mediaplayer').setup({
            'id': 'playerID',
            'width': '480',
            'height': '50',
            'file': baseURL + obj[i].FileName, 
            'provider': 'rtmp',
            'streamer': 'rmtp address',
            autostart: true,
            rtmp: {
                bufferlength: 10
            }
        }).onTime(function(){
            var totalDuration  = jwplayer('mediaplayer').getDuration();
            var currentPosition = jwplayer('mediaplayer').getPosition();
            if(parseInt(currentPosition/totalDuration) > .99 && buffernext!=true){
                buffernext = true;
                i = i +1;
                //Ready the next song to stream
            }
        });
```

How can I achieve the below tasks.

1. Buffer/stream song from AWS S3 bucket without changing file permission to 'open/download' as people download content from bucket.
2. Stream songs at some defined rate.
3. Start buffering the next song so avoid delay between two files.

Comment: Make the bufferlength 0.1, and since you are using RTMP, the files should not be downloadable by default.

Comment: what does 0.1 mean here...0.1% of the total length of file is buffered?